# Rename multiple files in a folder and its subfolders to a fixed pattern

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I have a large number of files to be renamed to a fixed pattern on my Windows 8 computer.
I am looking for a way so that I can rename the files in a quick way, any way: like any software that does it or any command on command window.

Following is what I need to do:

Original file name: Body Begger Power.docx.htm
Need this to be: body-begger-power.html

Answer (score 3):

From the root directory you can try this:

`Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {$_.FullName.ToLower() -replace ' ', '-'}`

I don't see any pattern for removing the extension. If all files are docx.html and you want them changed to html, you could simply do another replace like this:

`Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse | Move-Item -Destination {($_.FullName.ToLower() -replace ' ', '-') -replace '.docx.htm$', '.html'}`

Comment: @Chatur You tagged your question with powershell... Run cmd, then powershell, and then the given code.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /r %i in (.) do if exist "%i\body begger power.docx.htm" ECHO ren "%i\body begger power.docx.htm" body-begger-power.html
```

from the prompt will scan the tree from `.` (the current directory - or substitute the directoryname from which you want to start). This will simply ECHO the filenames detected to the screen - you need to remove the ECHO keyword to actually rename the file.